# Android theme error when adding a new dependency

Tags: android, dependencies

I'm following the examples on this sample from [github](https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera/blob/master/README.md) but when i add the dependency I recieve the error

> "
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-40
>       is also present at [com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.0.3] AndroidManifest.xml:11:18-76 value=(@style/squarecamera__CameraFullScreenTheme).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-81:19 to override."

I gather it's because im using this "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'" which is an older version and is conflicting with the theme from the added dependency.

however I want to avoid changing appcompat to a newer version because every activity i have relies on 22.2.1 and the change would be too great.

Are there any ways of working around this error? Or should i just look into another way of creating a square image from camera activity?